# Advise on setting up seed data using nhibernate during development (not test suite)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

How should one go about setting up seed data while developing an nhibernate web application? (It's Mvc)

Should I just create a method and have it fire during application load (when it debug mode), and simply comment it out when I don't need it?

or is there a better way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest looking at something like [AutoPoco](http://autopoco.codeplex.com/).

> AutoPoco replaces manually written object mothers/test data builders
> with a fluent interface and an easy way to generate a large amount of
> readable test data. By default, no manual set-up is required,
> conventions can then be written against the names/types of property or
> manual configuration can be used against specific objects.
>
> The primary use cases are
>
> - Creating single, valid objects for unit tests in a standard manner across all tests
> - Creating large amounts of valid test data for database population

This is not tied directly to NHibernate - you could in theory combine it with any data-layer that can persist POCO's.

I'd avoid adding code to Application_Start though - that sounds like a recipe for accidentally trashing your production database. You'd be better off creating a simple console application that you can run whenever you want to reseed your database.

Comment: Good answer :) But I feel you didn't really address the question. You pointed OP to third-party code and told them it might be better to not edit the Application_Startup. I would've expected to at least include some discussion about running SQL scripts, what you can do within an application, or dumping & reimporting a database, etc.